# What is the difference between virtual final and non-virtual?

Tags: c++, final, virtual-functions

What is the difference in between declaring a new (non override) member function `virtual final` versus just non-virtual?

I'm guessing a `virtual final` member function (that does not override anything) will be optimized to non-virtual by the compiler anyways, but maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: I suspect difference is in ABI of the resulting class.

Comment: `virtual void foo() final` makes the class polymorphic (so you might use `dynamic_cast` on it).

Comment: One difference is that a compiler will still have to initialize `vptr`.

Comment: @Evg who says there is a `vptr`?

Comment: @Caleth https://godbolt.org/z/qzoG7zrvn

Comment: @Evg, no, I mean what part of the standard says that virtual functions are implemented with something called `vptr`?

Comment: @Caleth Let's call it a practical difference. Are there compilers that implement virtual functions without `vptr`?

Comment: @Evg I haven't exhaustively checked, but I expect someone has written a very aggressively devirtualising compiler at some point, that would eliminate cases like this

Comment: @Caleth That would be an interesting thing to take a look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a virtual method means you are a legal target for dynamic casting, and you cannot be standard layout.

ABI wise I suspect compilers aren't going to do extra work to eliminate `final` methods, so the vtable with the entry will still exist unless the entire class is eliminated under "as-if".

But at every point of call, they can bypass the vtable and call the method directly (presuming the address of the method is known at the call site by the compiler; it is plausible some dynamic loading settings could make the vtable known at the call site, but the method address not).

This also prevents derived classes from overriding this exact signature.  Ie:

```
struct Parent {
  void foo();
};
struct Child:Parent {
  void foo();
};
```

this is legal, while

```
struct Parent {
  virtual void foo() final;
};
struct Child:Parent {
  void foo();
};
```

is not.  Relying on this is fragile, as

```
struct Parent {
  virtual void foo() final;
};
struct Child:Parent {
  void foo() const;
};
```

is again legal.

Comment: Ah ok, so virtual final blocks any Child from using the exact same signature , but it does not cost anything in terms of runtime right?

Comment: @Peter I did not say "it does not cost anything in terms of runtime".  I said it likely changes the ABI and prevents it from being standard layout and the vtable probably exists.  All of these have impact at runtime.  "does not cost anything" is an insanely strong demand, as even trivial costs make it fail.

Comment: Ok, sorry you are right. But it probably does not cost as much in runtime as one would suspect of a virtual method. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: "_ABI wise I suspect compilers aren't going to do extra work to eliminate final methods_": Even if they did that, it wouldn't change that the class is polymorphic, so that `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`'s behaviors on polymorphic types still need to work. So eliminating the vptr seems impossible to me either way.

Comment: @user17732522 only if someone actually does `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` such an object, and only if the compiler chooses not to as-if those into something else

Comment: @Caleth Except in trivial cases (like purely local object), you would global optimization to determine that.